# UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass Sticky and Stretchy header

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I use a `UICollectionView` with an unique section to split the logic of a large view. This one has a `HeaderView` with a picture and I've tried to make this header sticky and stretchy (when you scroll down the header became small until is just a bar and stick to the top, when you scroll up and bounce, the header come back to the picture and stretch).

I've read and watch many tutorials and try to make my own implementation, but each time, the same behaviour happened:

The cells doesn't scroll anymore and the header slide down.

Also every time I call:

```
collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

the collection view scroll back to the top without animation.

Below, the stretchy part only!

Here my CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout's code:

```
class CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect),
            let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return nil
        }

        let offset = collectionView.contentOffset
        if offset.y < 0 {
            let deltaY = abs(offset.y)
            for attributes in layoutAttributes {
                if attributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                    var frame = attributes.frame
                    frame.size.height = max(0, headerReferenceSize.height + deltaY)
                    frame.origin.y = frame.minY - deltaY
                    attributes.frame = frame
                }
            }
        }

        return layoutAttributes
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

And here how I link it with the CollectionViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? PINPropertyDetailsCollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let side = collectionView?.frame.width ?? 375
        flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: side, height: side)
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: side, height: 1)
    }
    collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

I've try to use:

```
flowLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

as well with no more results: nothing (cells or header) scroll anymore...

I use Xcode 9 (beta 4) coding for iOS 9 & 10.

Thanks for feedbacks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolve it by implementing `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and the method `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`.

The stretchy effect wasn't possible apparently without a fixed item size (until now I was using automatic size)